# Nginx rewrite to a different domain for a specific path

Tags: nginx

What I wish to do is, rewrite a URL which looks like this:

```
wiki.mydomain.com/simplesaml/module.php/core
```

to something like this:

```
sso.mydomain.com/simplesaml/module.php/core
```

All other URLs, like `wiki.mydomain.com/index.php/Article` etc. should continue to be served from `wiki.mydomain.com`. Both the domains `wiki.mydomain.com` and `sso.mydomain.com` are served by nginx itself and configured as virtual hosts. This is the rewrite rule I have come up with till now, but it doesn't work:

```
rewrite ^ http://wiki.nomadly.in/simplesaml/(*) http://sso.nomadly.in/simplesaml/$1 break;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: (.*) instead of (*)

Comment: Tried that.. still not working. It isn't rewriting it.

Comment: Once your request matches a server block, nginx will use the URI relative to this vhost in further processings. That why your rewrite directive will never match.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to redirect just `wiki.mydomain.com/simplesaml/modules.php/core`. you can use this:

```
rewrite /simplesaml/module.php/core http://sso.mydomain.com/simplesaml/module.php/core permanent;
```

If you want to redirect everything under /simplesaml to the same URI under `sso.mydomain.com`, use this:

```
location /simplesaml {
    rewrite ^ http://sso.mydomain.com$request_uri permanent;
}
```

Most important part is the `permanent` definition on the rewrite line, that causes nginx to send a `301` redirect to the new URL.